# Setting flag in database while inserting large xml

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails

I have a service that will read in xml and insert into a mysql database. There could be large or small files and the files would be in a queue. I have different flags in another table to signal what is being done to these files. If a file is being read it would say loading,if it were waiting to be read it would say not read and if it were in the table it would say loaded. The problem I am having is the flag doesn't seem to get set until after the hibernate session is complete. Most of the work occurs in a service but I call a .groovy class and it sets that status there with save(flush: true)..is there a way to force the session to set that flag while it is still reading and before the session completes?

Comment: The issue is your transaction isolation level isn't allowing the data to be read while the transaction isn't complete. You could either not use transactions, use separate transactions or change your isolation level to allow for "dirty reads" (or something similar).

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of separate transaction?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar process; it reads hundreds of thousands of rows from .csv files and we need the data to be interacted with sooner than the end of the load. Periodically (every 1,000 records), we call a method to flush the session. Could you implement something like this?

```
def cleanUpGorm() {
  def propertyInstanceMap = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DomainClassGrailsPlugin.PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP
  def session = sessionFactory.currentSession
  session.flush()
  session.clear()
  propertyInstanceMap.get().clear()
}
```